# Drag and drop to scroll position within HTML element using JavaScript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll, position

I'd like to allow the user to drag and drop to a certain position inside of an HTML element (ie: DIV) relative to the current position, assuming the HTML element has content.  I've only found examples where you can drag and drop an element within another element.

So basically I'd like to drag the browser window position to a different x/y location, similar to how Google Maps behaves.  Although in my case, there is a height and width for the element, but I want to avoid showing a horizontal scroll bar and a vertical scroll bar.  Is this possible with some JavaScript library?  If so, can you point me to an example?

## **Edit**

*Noticing some strange things happening when you drag the rectangles across the screen.*

**Take this jFiddle..**

http://jsfiddle.net/08p1dm0x/1/

**..and add an external reference to:**

```
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js
```

**Then add this line..**

```
$("#gfx_holder").draggable();
```

**..to the on ready function:**

```
$(function() {
```

Comment: You can accomplish this easily with jquery.  Do you want that answer,or regular JavaScript?

Comment: Either or is fine.  Whatever has less code and is cross browser compatible.  I thought about it for a minute and I suppose I could just use body as my parent element and the div element as the child, and just put all of my content (for the page) inside of the child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should accomplish what you're looking for.  It uses the jquery ui draggable extension to make elements draggable inside the "viewport".  The overflow:hidden on the viewport prevents the scrollbar.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning canvas</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
   html, body, #viewPort
   {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
   }
   #map
   {
    position:relative;
     height:1523px;
     width:3000px;
     background-image:url(http://www.mapplace.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/world-map-2.jpg);
   }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#map").draggable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="viewPort">
    <div id="map"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see EDIT... notice how things get dragged twice as far as you scroll

Comment: I wonder if jQuery has a swallowEvent function so I can ignore the jquery-ui drag and drop when the mouse starts on top of a draw2d element?

Comment: Ah,  you have two drag handlers running at the same time.  I thought you wanted to move the whole canvas like google maps.  It looks like what you really want is to just drag the items in there, but without scroll bars.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather have the whole canvas move!!  Although if the mouse starts from one of those boxes (in my example), the draw2d-js library should take over.

Comment: There's an event.preventDefault() method which does exactly that.

Comment: Did any of this help?

Comment: No.  draw2d-js/raphael uses the same exact library, so it's applying the affects twice.  In Raphael, it applies the affect to the nodes, and in my case, I'm applying it to the entire div (entire canvas).  Need to figure out how to ignore the raphael calls if you don't drag and drop a node.  How can that be done?

Comment: I did end up using the CSS, but instead with a configuration file and using the CSS compiler that Sencha had.  Just never accepted this as the answer years ago.  Haha!  I guess in basketball, two points is a field goal.  So we can call it a StackOverflow field goal.